# When I do a hard refresh, react is not rendered and the JSON from Rails is rendered on the screen, how do get react to render?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

When I am on the homepage the "/", I can do a hard refresh and react will render, but the minute I go past the homepage and do a hard refresh react is no longer being displayed.

Here are my routes in the react side

```
 <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
 <Route exact path="/categories/:id" component={Products} />
 <Route path="/categories/:id/products/:id" component={Product} />
```

I did notice once I get passed the home page I see this being called in the rails server
Rendering home/index.html.erb within layouts/application
and when I am in categories or in products on the rails server side the layout/application isn't being called.

I am using rails 6.

Please and thank you for anyones help
The JSON shows when I hit refresh, the one below it is when use the navigation bar and don't hit refresh. Refresh has the reach items not appear.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the react app running in development or on a production server or CDN? If production, the specific environment probably has requirements for handling the routing of requests. If development, then check your React router is correctly set up, and Rails routes redirect non JSON requests back to your root/home page. Also check the browser console for errors.

Comment: I am in development mode,  JSON is being returned. React doesn't render on a refresh past the root. Let me see if I can add an image

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcard routes in your `routes.rb` file ,
`get "*path", to: "home#index", via: :all`
and write this at the bottom of the file